# How to disable warnings at solution level in .NET projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core

I referred to many blogs that are suggesting to suppress warnings or errors at the project level but my concern is to suppress the same warning at solution level.

I found a workaround to suppress warnings or errors at solution level using .editorConfig file present under the Solution Items folder under our VisualStudio solution. But this .editorConfig file will suppress warnings/errors in VisualStudio solution but not in Build pipelines

Could someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create one `GlobalSuppressions.cs` file (I created for one project then cut and paste in solution level) in solution level.

You can add `GlobalSuppressions.cs` file in each project 'As a Link'. And It will work with VisualStudio and the build pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for valid and immediate response

Comment: welcome..you can mark as answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: How to suppress 1 warning specifically in 2 projects in case of Solutionlevel suppression
Ex:   
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Design", "CA1001:Types that own disposable fields should be disposable", Justification = "<Pending>", Scope = "type", Target = "~T:ProjectName1.ClassName1")]
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Design", "CA1001:Types that own disposable fields should be disposable", Justification = "<Pending>", Scope = "type", Target = "~T:ProjectName1.ClassName2")]  
Note: Instead of writing 2 times, i want to write at 1 time.

Answer (score -1):

You can use argument to the compiler.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/warn-compiler-option

Comment: No, that is not a solution level solution but a project level one. OP need to do it in the solution